# Does the python garbage collector remove cyclical references?

Tags: python, oop

I read on this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destructors-in-python/ that the garbage collector detects cyclical references and removes them. If so, how come the cyclical reference in this code doesn't seem to get removed (I'm assuming that since the print statements don't raise an attribute error):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, other_instance):
        self.other_instance = other_instance

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A object'

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.other_instance = A(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'B object'

obj = B()
print(obj.other_instance.other_instance)
print(obj.other_instance)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: While the code is running, the objects are not yet garbage.

Comment: point of garbage collection is to prevent these things python is not rust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It detects and clears cyclical references **in garbage** - objects that are no longer reachable. Your objects are not garbage.

It is by design impossible to inspect objects at a point after the garbage collector has cleared their cyclical references, as doing so would require the objects to still be reachable.

(Note that the article you're reading is out of date, and it wasn't great even before then. The interaction between `__del__` and the garbage collector doesn't work like the article describes any more.)

Comment: So by not in garbage/still reachable do you mean that they're reference count is not 0. And if so, that confuses me even more cause if the reference count is 0 doesn't it get cleared anyway irrelevant if its a cyclical reference or not.

Comment: @piny: No. An object is reachable if you can get to the object by following a chain of references from certain "root" references, like local variables of function calls still on the stack. (Python's GC system doesn't actually have a way to determine a set of "root" references, so it uses a different approach to detecting garbage, but the concept of reachability still implies.)

Comment: @piny I think you are misunderstanding how reference-counting garbage collectors work, and what a cycle means in that context. I suggest reading [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Reference_counting) to begin with.